# Troubles with my .h files

Tags: c++, header, include

Here are my two classes, Node and DobleNode, both of them are in a different .h file and both of them have their own .cpp file as well.

```
//"Node.h" 

class Node
{
public:

    Node(string pName, string pID);
    void setReferencia(DobleNode *pReferencia);
    DobleNode* getReferencia(void);

private:

    string Name;
    string ID;
    DobleNode *referencia;
};

//"DobleNode.h"

class DobleNode
{
public:

    DobleNode(string pBank_code, string pCard_type);
    void setReferencia(Node *pReferencia);
    Node* getReferencia(void);

private:

    string bank_code;
    string card_type;
    Node *referencia;
};
```

The problem is that I need to have a reference. In the class Node, there must be an attribute of type DobleNode, and in the class DobleNode there must be an attribute of type Node. It seems to be really simple, I just have to include "DobleNode.h" before "Node.h" and everything will work...

But if I do this, later on, when I try to compile my little program it says that the identifier Node does not exist. And if I do it the other way, it says the same thing, but this time the identifier DobleNode is the one that does not exist.

How can I solve this, I think a solution might be to have both classes in the same file, but I really think there is a better way of solving this.
Is there a way to "tell" the compiler to check both "Node.h" and "DobleNode.h" at the same time, or something?

Thanks for your answer.

BTW I'm working on Visual Studio 2010 Proffesional, C++ (clearly).

Comment: Can't you simply use a forward declaration? Or haven't you tried that yet?

Comment: hahaha easy as that, I just had to use forward declaration!! thanks!

Answer (score 5):

You can forward-declare a class, since you are using pointers.

```
//"DobleNode.h"

class Node;   // DECLARED!  "Node.h" doesn't need to be included.

class DobleNode
{
    ...
```

and

```
//"Node.h" 

class DobleNode;   // DECLARED!  "DobleNode.h" doesn't need to be included.

class Node
{
    ...
```

Comment: Wow! that was simple, hahaha, now it works perfectly fine! Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

Put "class Node;" and "class DobleNode;" at the top of one/both headers.

e.g. (with structs)

```
struct node1;
struct node2;

struct node1 { struct node2 *p; };
struct node2 { struct node1 *p; };
```

It works the same with classes.

Answer (score 1):

You are having the problem because if two files include each other this results in infinite circular inclusion.  To avoid this your code likely has pre-compiler headers in it telling it to not include code that's already been included.  However, this results in one of your classes not having the other defined

There are two solutions.  You can forward-declare as described by Drew Dormann.

However I'm guessing for your purpose using a virtual class that both Node and DoubleNode inherit from may be more suitable, since you seem to have simular methods in each.  This would save your from duplicating your code for common methods and make editing easier.

for example

```
//"Node.h" 

class Node : public NodeBase
{
public:

private:

    string Name;
    string ID;
};

//"DobleNode.h"

class DobleNode : public NodeBase
{
public:

private:

    string bank_code;
    string card_type;
};

//"NodeBase.h" 

class NodeBase
{
public:

    Node(string pName, string pID);
    void setReferencia(NodeBase *pReferencia);
    NodeBase* getReferencia(void);

protected:
    NodeBase *referencia;
};
```